# Select value and text does not show for select with one option

Tags: javascript, html, forms, select, thymeleaf

I am using this code to set a select in a form.

```
    <td>
       <select class="orderNo" th:name="OrderNo" th:value="${order.subOrderNo}"  th:text="${order.subOrderName}">
           <option class="coNameOption" th:value="${order.subOrderNo}"  th:text="${order.subOrderName}" selected></option>
        </select>
    </td>
```

the html part when i inspect seems to have the proper value and to place the text there.

But on screen the select box is empty and does not show the text.

I also tried to place the text in option in span but it also does not work

Comment: why extra `th:` in atrribute ?

Comment: i use thymeleaf. i seems that option is not recognized at all. Cause i have commented the option part and it is exactly the same.

Comment: Can you please post your controller code?  Also, you don't need to prefix `th:` when there is nothing Thymeleaf needs to evaluate.  This is true for `th:name="OrderNo"`.

Comment: fixed it i had to remove the th:text from the select part , only th:value worked. For the name you are correct th: is not in need

Answer (score 0):

`th:text` overwrites anything inside the html tags.  You shouldn't have `th:text` or `th:value` on a `<select />` tag.

```
<td>
  <select class="orderNo" name="OrderNo" >
    <option class="coNameOption" th:value="${order.subOrderNo}"  th:text="${order.subOrderName}" selected="selected" />
  </select>
</td>
```